# How can I see the current bit depth of the playing audio stream?

Tags: sound, alsa, music

I've disabled PulseAudio, I'm only using ALSA. How can I see the current bit depth of the playing audio stream?

Here's the output of */proc/asound/card1/pcm0p/sub0/hw_params*

## When playing a 16 bit, 44.1KHz song:

```
access: RW_INTERLEAVED
format: S24_3LE
subformat: STD
channels: 2
rate: 44100 (44100/1)
period_size: 2205
buffer_size: 8820
```

## When playing a 24 bit, 96KHz song:

```
access: RW_INTERLEAVED
format: S24_3LE
subformat: STD
channels: 2
rate: 96000 (96000/1)
period_size: 4800
buffer_size: 19200
```

Here's the output of */proc/asound/card1/stream0*

## When playing a 16 bit, 44.1KHz song:

```
  Status: Running
  Interface = 1
  Altset = 1
  Packet Size = 402
  Momentary freq = 44100 Hz (0x2c.1998)
  Feedback Format = 10.14
```

## When playing a 24 bit, 96KHz song:

```
  Status: Running
  Interface = 1
  Altset = 1
  Packet Size = 585
  Momentary freq = 96000 Hz (0x60.0000)
  Feedback Format = 10.1
```

I can see the sampling rate frequency, but how can I see if the bit depth is 16-bit or 24-bit?

Answer (score 1):

The `hw_params` file shows the sample format in the `format:` line.
`S24_3LE` indicates 24-bit, little-endian samples.

The `streamX` file shows the sample format in the "Interface" section of the selected "Altset".

Comment: I'm curious, why it's always S24_3LE (24-bit) even when I'm playing 16-bit files?

Comment: Does your device have an altsetting with 16 bits?

Comment: I'm not sure. It's an Arcam rDAC that according to the specs can receive over USB the following: 32kHz, 44.1kHz, 48kHz, 88.2kHz, 96kHz and a bit depth of 16-bit — 24-bit. If this is not what you're referring to, how can I check? Is it ALSA that is configured to do everything at 24bit?

Comment: All formats are listed in the `stream0` file.

Comment: These are the contents of the stream while playing:
ARCAM ARCAM DAC at usb-0000:00:14.0-4, full speed : USB Audio

Playback:
  Status: Running
    Interface = 1
    Altset = 1
    Packet Size = 402
    Momentary freq = 44100 Hz (0x2c.1998)
    Feedback Format = 10.14
  Interface 1
    Altset 1
    Format: S24_3LE
    Channels: 2
    Endpoint: 1 OUT (ASYNC)
    Rates: 32000, 44100, 48000, 88200, 96000
    Bits: 24

The stuff under "Interface 1" never changes

Comment: If there aren't other entries with other Altset numbers, then the hardware does not support other formats.

Comment: I only have one Altset when looking at stream0.